# After chown 777 to the folder, it is still blocked

Tags: chmod, chown

## chmod

```
chmod -R 777 /media
chmod -R 777 /media/guoyi
chmod -R 777 /media/guoyi/pc
```

Then it is still blocked and I use

```
ln -s /media/guoyi/pc/x /home/guoyi/desktop
```

Then the link is also blocked.
What's the problem and any solution?

## chown

Then I try to change the owner of the folder `/media/guoyi/pc` due to the owner is `root` not `guoyi`

```
sudo chown -R guoyi /media
sudo chown -R guoyi /media/guoyi
sudo chown -R guoyi /media/guoyi/pc
```

It still shows that the owner of the folder is `root`

## Note

### about the block

the block situation. The lock icon on the folder
Image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDK5A.png

### about the operating system and folder

The operating system is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the `/media/guoyi/pc` is the partition of Windows 10 system.

```
guoyi@Helix:/media/guoyi$ ls -l
总用量 16
drwxrwxrwx 1 guoyi guoyi 4096 April  11 22:24 5F5F69E074927314
drwxrwxrwx 2 guoyi guoyi 4096 April   10 19:56 disk
drwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  8192 April   14 15:33 pc
```

### Additional Information

I have auto mount the patition by the following command

```
sudo blkid
```

Output information shows

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="240EDFFC0EDFC4C8" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="b2f82fdc-cd30-4785-ae68-7111eb344e64"
```

then

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and then write the following at the end of the file

```
UUID=240EDFFC0EDFC4C8 /media/guoyi/pc ntfs default 0 2
```

Comment: What do you mean it is "blocked"?

Comment: @Nmath see the png file.

Comment: You have provided no OS & release details, nor specifics on what *file-system* is involved and if it can handle POSIX file attributes, or relies on masking etc...

Comment: Can you provide the "ls -lrt" so that the actual owner of the folder is known. If the actual owner is root. You have to first to sudo su and log in as the root user. Then you can change the ownership of the folder to guoyi.

Comment: Thanks, @guiverc , Operating system is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. `/media/guoyi/pc` is the windows 10 patition.

Comment: @TaraMishra I now add.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Explore your permission/ownership problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld